# Stack Exchange app -> Stack Overflow area won't let me edit questions, but webpage does

Tags: support, bug, android-app, ios-app

I don't seem to be able to edit questions via phone on the Stack Exchange app on Stack Overflow. I get an error that says the account isn't allowed to edit questions. However I can on the web page. Any suggestions?

Comment: Surprisingly, I don't see a duplicate on MSO.  But it is because you cannot suggest edits via the API (which is what the iOS and Android App use),  See [this post on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208471/android-app-should-send-edits-to-edit-queue-if-necessary-rather-than-rejecting-t).

Comment: It would be nice if they just said that they didn't support it. I hope they implement that feature soon! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is quite misleading, but they were going to say that apps (there are two apps: for iOS and for Android) don't support pushing suggested edits to review queues. Don't know what made them use this message.

Answer (score 2):

Now, as of 2015, you can suggest edits in both the Android and iOS Stack Exchange apps.